# jquery tabs, reload page for each tab

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, redirect, jquery-tabs

Using jQuery ui tabs, is there an effective way to reload the page for each tab?

I tried doing

```
$('#tab_two').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://localhost/page#tab_two';
    });
```

But, that still lands on the current page.  However, if you refresh the page after that then it will redirect to #tab_two.

The only way to effectively redirect the page seems to be using PHP.  But having

```
$('#tab_two').click(function() {
    header('location: http://localhost/page#tab_two');
    });
```

messes up the page.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `load` method like I did below:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

   $( "#tab_two" ).click(function() {
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "load" , 1 );   // zero-based (tab#1 = 0 index)
   });
});
```

Documentation:

> **.tabs( "load" , index )** Reload the content of an Ajax tab
>   programmatically. This method always loads the tab content from the
>   remote location, even if cache is set to true. The second argument is
>   the zero-based index of the tab to be reloaded.